# Problem with indexOf on JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

```
var allProductIDs = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795, 5775, 1004, 1008, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1072, 1076, 1086, 1111, 1112, 1140];

lastProductID = 6758;
```

for some reason I get a -1 or I guess which is equivalent to not found for this:

```
alert(allProductIDs[allProductIDs.indexOf(lastProductID));
```

I can't figure out for the life of my why because it should find 6758 and that would be index 3. If it's index 3 then I should get back 6758 I would think.

Comment: For what it's worth, yes -1 means not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.indexOf()` is used for strings, not arrays.

Using regular Javascript you'll have to loop through the array until you find a match, or use the `inArray()` function of jQuery.

[jQuery inArray()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray#valuearray)

Comment: nice.  Was not aware of that.  Is there a shortuct to having to use jQuery. such as can you use $.inArray() or something like that?

Comment: tried this but it loops infinitely and gives me a -1 every damn time:  

            for(i = 0; i < numberOfImagesToDisplay; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) { addIndex = productIDs.length + 1; }

                alert(allProductIDs[jQuery.inArray(lastProductID) + i]);
                productIDs[addIndex] = allProductIDs[jQuery.inArray(lastProductID) + i];
            }

Comment: it also throws my program in an infinite loop!  weird.

Comment: apparently arrays have .indexOf() in JavaScript 1.6 and later though:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - It should have been "i < numberOfImagesToDisplay.length"

Comment: @newacct: Not in IE6 though <shakes fist at Bill Gates>

Answer (score 3):

```
var allProductIDs = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795, 5775, 1004, 1008, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1072, 1076, 1086, 1111, 1112, 1140];

lastProductID = 6758;

for (i in allProductIDs)
{
    if (allProductIDs[i] == lastProductID) {
        alert(allProductIDs[i] + " is at index " + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
i = $.inArray(lastProductID, allProductIDs)
alert(allProductIDs[i] + " is at index " + i);
```

Comment: any idea why my program would be thrown into an infinite loop with the following :             for(i = 0; i < numberOfImagesToDisplay; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) { addIndex = productIDs.length + 1; }

                //alert(allProductIDs[jQuery.inArray(lastProductID) + i]);
                productIDs[addIndex] = allProductIDs[jQuery.inArray(lastProductID) + i];
            }

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax too. You are missing an end bracket ..']'